# CMD how to write merged text file name on first line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have created cmd batch file to run several R script and each script have their own log files in same folder like below :

```
coc_prod_xgb.log
ds_prod_xgb.log
ccpa_prod_xgb.log
pletb_prod_xgb.log
```

and many more

Then I merge all text files into 1 log file

```
copy *.log all_log.log
```

The problem is sometimes there are errors on different jobs, so I need to know on which log this error occurs. Currently I have to open each log file one by one, because in the merged log file, I can't identify which log file that has this error.

How to modify above `copy` code so it will write file names on the 1st row then the next row will be log information and append the same process to next file

Comment: What about `find /V "" "*._xgb.log" > "all_log.log" 2>&1`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any option for cmd copy code to write file name, so i find another solution from this question.

[Easiest way to add a text to the beginning of another text file in Command Line (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550728/easiest-way-to-add-a-text-to-the-beginning-of-another-text-file-in-command-line)

so it serve my needs, eventhough i have to write each block of code for each log file. but only for 1 time effort