# Insert header in a csv file with command line Windows

Tags: windows, csv, command-line

I have a .csv file with some data, for example:

```
a | b | c | d | e
f | g | h | i | f
```

I would like to insert a header in this file to indicate each field:

```
h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5
a | b | c | d | e
f | g | h | i | l
```

I would like to do it from the Windows command line, how can I do?

Answer (score 3):

First, write the header to a new text file (escape the pipe symbol `|` using `^`)

```
echo h1 ^| h2 ^| h3 ^| h4 ^| h5 > combined.csv
```

Then append the original file to this newly created file:

```
type originalfile.csv >> combined.csv
```

At last, you overwrite the original file with the content of the new file (including the header line)

```
type combined.csv > originalfile.csv
--or--
move /Y combined.csv originalfile.csv
```

---

Based on these answers: [using batch echo with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308586) and [Easiest way to add a text to the beginning of another text file in Command Line (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550728)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) and run

```
mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header --fs "|" label h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 input.csv
```

to have

```
h1|h2|h3|h4|h5
a|b|c|d|e
f|g|h|i|f
```

- `--csv` to set the format
- `--implicit-csv-header` to declare that the input has no heading
- `--fs "|"` to set the field separator
- `label h1,h2,h3,h4,h5` to set the heading